# Does property (V) imply the Grothendieck property for dual Banach spaces?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

A Banach space $X$ has *property (V)* whenever for each Banach space $Y$, every unconditionally converging operator $T:X\to Y$ is weakly compact; equivalently, every non-weakly compact operator $T:X\to Y$ is an isomorphism on a subspace of $X$ isomorphic to $c_0$.

The space $X$ has the *Grothendieck property* whenever for each separable Banach space $Y$, every operator $T:X\to Y$ is weakly compact.

Exercise VII.12 in J. Diestel's book "[Sequences and series in Banach spaces](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-5200-9)" (Springer 1984) asks to prove that, for a dual space $X^*$,  property (V) implies the Grothendieck property. It suggest to keep in mind Phillips's lemma.

Can anyone suggest an argument or a reference for the proof?

Note: Since separable spaces with the Grothendieck property are reflexive, the space $c_0$ shows that the result fails for non-dual spaces.

Comment: A Banach space $X$ with property (V) is a Grothendieck space if and only if it contains no complemented copy of $c_0$. Also $c_0$ cannot be complemented in any dual space. Consequently, Any dual Banach space with property (V) is a Grothendieck space.

Comment: You are right. Nice argument.

Comment: It was goofy of me to focus too much on the question that I missed at the first look who posted it. To my defense, I was writing as I was defending my computer heroically from my 7 year-old daughter who was acting up because she thinks it is her God given right to watch her favorite cartoon on every internet connected machine at home. What I wrote is the same as Proposition 3.1.13 in https://doi.org/10.1007/s11537-021-2116-3 which provided a shorter, nicer proof. Sir, thank you for your kind reply and for this small exchange, I'm happy that you've found my footnote worthwhile.

Comment: Thank you for your remark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I need a few preliminaries:

A Banach space $X$ is a Grothendieck space if and only if every bounded linear $T:X\to c_0$ is weakly compact.

A bounded linear operator $T:X\to Y$, between two Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$, is either unconditionally converging or fixes a copy of $c_0$.

If $V$ is a subspace of $c_0$ that is isomorphic to $c_0$, then it contains a subspace $W\subseteq V$ that is also isomorphic to $c_0$ and complemented in $c_0$.

---

After this, let $X$ be a dual Banach space with property (V), and $T:X\to c_0$ be a bounded linear operator. Either $T$ is unconditionally converging or $T$ fixes a copy of $c_0$.

Suppose for a contradiction that $T$ fixes a copy of $c_0$, i.e., there exists $V\subseteq X$ a copy of $c_0$, and the restriction $T:V\to T(V)$ is an isomorphism. $T(V)\subseteq c_0$ is isomorphic to $c_0$, so there exists a complemented subspace $W\subseteq T(V)\subseteq c_0$ isomorphic to $c_0$. Clearly, $T:T^{-1}(W)\to W$ is an isomorphism, $T^{-1}(W)$ is complemented in $X$. On the other hand, *since $X$ is a dual Banach space*, it cannot contain a complemented copy of $c_0$. Contradiction.

By contradiction, $T:X\to c_0$ is unconditionally converging. *Since $X$ has property (V)*, $T$ is weakly compact.

Comment: Each copy of $c_0$ in $c_0$ is complemented.

Comment: Professor @M.González, thanks for your remark. Surely $c_0$ is separably injective.